# How to call subsequent callbacks in loop?

Tags: node.js, loops, for-loop, foreach, callback

In my Nodejs application I need to select a set of data from the database by some queries. An amount of queries not defined at the start and I need to check after each DB query whether I need to make another query or not. So the process like this

```
var total_result = [];
var n = 0;
db.query('.....query...', function(result, error){
    // Callback with db data response
    total_results.push(...result...);
    n += result.length;

    if (n < req_n) {
        // ... Here is the code to repeat the same query ...
        // ?????
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var total_result = [],
    n            = 0

while(await query())

async function query() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    db.query('...query...', (result, error) => {
      if(error) reject(error)
      // Callback with db data response
      total_results.push(...result...)
      n += result.length

      if (n < req_n) resolve(true)
      else resolve(false)
   })
  })
}
```